# Specifying web app domain name in resource manager template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am currently trying to create Resource Manager Template files for azure web apps. Nothing complicated initially, just deploying a website from a [GitHub template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-web-app-github-deploy)

As the raw template it works fine, however now I am trying to make it automatically attach the domain name. This is the relevant section of the resource file:

```json
"apiVersion": "2015-04-01",
"name": "TDtestSimpleSiteWP",
"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
"location": "West Europe",
"dependsOn": [
  "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', 'TDtestSimpleSiteSP')]"
],
"properties": {
  "serverFarmId": "TDtestSimpleSiteSP",
  "hostnames": [
    "www.example.uk",
      "tdtestSimpleSitewp.azurewebsites.net"
  ],
  "enabledHostNames": [
    "www.example.uk",
      "tdtestSimpleSitewp.azurewebsites.net",
      "tdtestSimpleSitewp.scm.azurewebsites.net"
  ],
},
```

the `enabledHostNames` section is the latest addition to test if that made any difference, it didn't. Neither did adding a `hostNameSslStates`.

The error I am now receiving is:

```
'There are no host names which could be used for validation.'
```

If I add the site through the portal it accepts the DNS validation is done, so I know its not a DNS issue.

I have looked through the relevant [schema](http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-06-01/Microsoft.Web.json) but can't find anything there that looks relevant.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure whether this should be here or on ServerFault...

Answer (score 7):

Was currently doing some research for this, and found out that it can be done.

Variables

```json
"webSiteName": "yourawesomewebapp"
"customDomain": "www.example.com"
```

Template

```json
{
  "name": "[concat(variables('webSiteName'),'/',variables('customDomain'))]",
  "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings",
  "location": "West Europe",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "siteName": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
    "domainId": null,
    "hostNameType": "Verified"
  }
}
```

Try https://resources.azure.com/ for a stripped down RM/JSON azure portal, very useful for stuff like this.

Answer (score 4):

This may help, looks like it is not supported to create the external binding at the time of web app creation but could be done as a second step...

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/59767145-36bd-45c3-ace8-f773538532bd/writing-arm-template-for-web-app-with-specified-hostnames-and-hostnamesslstates?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview&prof=required

Comment: Thank you! That certainly looks like something to play around with - You've actually beaten Azure support to answer this (I opened a case around the same time - I'm still waiting for a response!)

Comment: Vote for this to get fixed here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/12340926-configure-hostnames-for-web-app-in-arm-template

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error when deploying sites with websites behind a traffic manager. Template exported from portal included traffic manager endpoints in hostnames and enabledHostNames. After removing them - everything was created and proper entries (from traffic manager) were added automatically by Azure to hostnames.

I know that this question is old, but maybe my experience will help someone :)

Comment: Certainly helped me :)